# Issue when trying to stream a video from Google Drive inside HTML5 <video>

Tags: html, video, streaming, google-drive-api

This is my code:

```
<video preload="metadata" controls>
  <source 
    src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5i16Q7VQGPdaWozX0hORUFXVWc/video.mp4" 
    type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/E782R/4/

**Live demo (fullpage):** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/E782R/4/show/light/

If you're wondering where the URL is coming from, it's provided by Google Drive (right click on video -> "Details and activity").

[image]

I've put the video in a [publicly shared folder](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5i16Q7VQGPdaWozX0hORUFXVWc&usp=sharing). You can open the folder and then click on the video. It will start playing in a web player.

The problem is that my code does not work for some reason. Open my demo in Chrome and check the Network panel in the browser's DevTools. You will see that the request is canceled:

[image]

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the video itself has to be in html5 format for it to play using an html5 player. here's a link to more info ['convert any video to html5'](http://easyhtml5video.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder

[image: Create a folder]

Call it anything

[image: Name folder]

Share the folder

[image: Share folder]

...as public on the web. Note the id= part of the url

[image: Share as public]

Upload content to folder. It's now hosted at https://googledrive.com/host/[folder id]/[filename], eg https://googledrive.com/host/0B28BnxIvH5DuVTRZUHdueFl2ZFk/hello.html

Comment: But that's what I tried. Notice the URL format in the code block in my question. Also, notice how Drive will provide this "hosting URL" (right-click on file -> Details). *** I've checked my demo again. Last time, the HTTP request for the video file was canceled (for some reason; see screen in my question), but not it goes through and the video starts playing after 1-2 minutes.

Comment: I've also checked in IE11. The video starts playing, too, but again, after a lengthy loading period.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't read the question properly at all. Let me have a proper look into this. Really sorry.

Comment: So, to reiterate, when using that "hosting link" (provided by Drive), the <video> *does* start playing - so technically it works - but the loading period, ~1-2minutes, is unacceptably long. That same video plays after a few seconds when watched via the web player on Drive (compressed and sized-down, granted). I feel like it should be possible to speed up the reproduction via an HTML or JavaScript setting, but I'm not familiar with the API for this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive has some kind of bug or "feature" with hotlinking mp4 files. I'm guessing this is something intentional to force you to use the video sharing feature of Drive, so that they can save bandwidth, but I don't know. They always 403 after a while. You could try using webm, apparently it doesn't happen with webm files.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to get the video using curl but the server returned `403 Forbidden`. Probably the same is happening inside the browser.

That link you have is probably the wrong link (when used the server probably expects session cookies and what not). Try with the share link. To get the share link click the share button, then click `change`, then `Public on the web` and then copy the links that is at the top of the dialog box. This worked for me.

Comment: The video already *is* shared since it is located in a publicly shared folder (as I stated in my question). The "share link" does not work - it points to a HTML page with the video inside a web player. Obviously, you cannot load an HTML page inside a `<video>` element (I tried it, still. It didn't work). You can see that the URL I use in my demo is a "hosting link". Look at the screenshot for confirmation. Notice that it ends with ".mp4" indicating that it points to the video file directly.